# WinForms Startup Event not being handled

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-5

I have a Windows Forms Application in .NET 5 with Application Framework activated and the startup object set to (my) `MainForm`.
Using "View Application Events" in the application's properties, I auto-generated the `ApplicationEvents.vb` file and with the given controls auto-generated a method to do something on Startup (as I understand before even the `MainForm` loads) - but nothing in this method gets run, not even breakpoints are triggered.
I would assume an auto-generated sub in an auto-generated file designed for this should work and every other event handling sub does, just not Startup's.

This is my `ApplicationEvents.vb` (without the auto-generated comment):

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            Debug.Print("Test")
            MsgBox("Test")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

###### Background:

I'm trying to enable high DPI scaling for my application.
For this I've tried using the `app.manifest` file (opened by "View Windows Settings" in the application's properties), but no combination of tags I found in the docs worked (I'm running the required version of Windows 10 of cause).
The same for the `app.config` file, but I expected this because it's a .NET Framework feature to use it for that.
So I landed on `Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode)`. This worked when put into the `MainForm`'s `Load`event, but it only did what was intended when the form was already loaded and it was then put on a scaled up screen / the screen was scaled up while it was already loaded.
If it was started on an already scaled screen, it looked jumbled.
So I figured that enabling it only on the form loading is just a bit too late and it should be run asap, so I landed on Startup.

Comment: Probably you have already read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Mary Yes, I did. The `app.manifest` was already pre-generated and I uncommented the relevant lines according to this and also tried edits according to differing docs and posts. The `app.config` method doesn't work for .NET 5, it only works for the .NET Framework >= v4.7.
It's pretty hard to find documentation for .NET 5 exclusively, most is for .NET Framework or doesn't specifiy.

Comment: That Startup event handler works just fine.  Use Project > Properties > Application tab and ensure that the "Startup object" setting is still set to "Sub Main" and the "Enable application framework" checkbox is still ticked.  The comments in ApplicationEvents.vb show how to enable high-dpi, but if the Startup event handler doesn't run then ApplyHighDpiMode() won't run either.  A jumbled layout is otherwise a good indication what will happen on a user's machine whose monitor is not operating at a high-dpi setting.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, the error was that I've set my Startup object to `MainForm` instead of `Sub Main`, which before never made a difference and was more intuitive to me as I didn't know where the main sub is located in a WinForms app. I think it's changed in the `Application.myapp` file. The jumbled layout only happened under the specified conditions, besides that it was scaled up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup object has to be `Sub Main` for the Startup event to work, **not** `MainForm` (or any form at all).
(Thanks to *@Hans Passant* for the tip.)

If you want to change which one is the main form later on you have to do the following:

1. Close your project in Visual Studio.
2. Open your project's folder in explorer.
3. In it, open folder `My Project`.
4. Open `Application.myapp` with any text editor.
5. Change the form between the `<MainForm>` tags to your (new) main forms name.
6. Save and close.
7. Open `ApplicationDesigner.vb` with any text editor.
8. Find the following line and change *YourMainFormsName* to your (new) main forms name:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
    Me.MainForm = Global.YourProjectsName.YourMainFormsName
End Sub
```

9. Save and close.
10. Open your project again and start it up. The startup form should have changed.

This way you can keep the application framework and don't have to write your own `Sub Main`.